# Does standard clone button excludes fields not present on pagelayout

Tags: page-layout, clone

Does standard clone button clones fields present only on the page layout and not exactly a 'obj.clone() functionality?

Note: I tried clone by removing a field from pagelayout and I donot see that value copied. Is this a standard behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's standard behavior. It's really just like creating a new record manually, though it does have some additional logic available in triggers/workflows to detect a clone. If you wanted to copy additional values (e.g. hidden fields), you could write a trigger for this. Note that the features used to detect cloning (e.g. formula `ISCLONE()` and Apex Code's `sObject.isClone()`) are currently broken, and is currently [under review](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYveQAG) if you want to be notified when this is fixed.